# What is the source to find cardinal invariants for a function space C(X, Y), equipped with uniform or fine topology?

Tags: gn.general-topology, function-spaces

I would like to know about the technique to check the cardinality properties for the function space C(X, Y), where X is a tychonoff space and Y a metric space, equipped with uniform or fine topology.

Comment: Please can you make explicit: What are cardinal properties of $C(X,Y)$? Why has the topology an influence?

Comment: By Cardinality of C(X, Y) endowed with uniform or fine topology, i mean to study the cardinal invariants such as Character, Density, Weight, Cellularity etc.

Answer (score 1):

There is a book called *Function Spaces with Uniform, Fine and Graph Topologies* by Robert A. McCoy, Subiman Kundu, Varun Jindal. I haven´t read it but it has a chapter called *Cardinal Functions and Countability Properties*. I would start there.

Comment: That book contains the cardinality of a special case C(X), that means when Y= real line R. I want to explore the cardinal invariants of the space C(X, Y).